# My webpage stops loading when reaching a php tag in javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I have a problem with a website which I never had before on other sites, it's probably something simple, but can't seem to get it. Please see and advise.

```
<!--All Header Elements-->
<?php 
$pageName = "Easy-Quote";
$siteName = "Bloemendal";
include("../Includes/header_non_index.inc"); 
include("../Includes/function12.inc"); 
?> <?php error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); ?>
<!--All Header Elements-->
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

var total = 0;

var allVenues = "";
var allVenuePricing = "";
var allTents = "";
var allTentPricing = "";
var allDFPricing = "";
var allMenus = "";
var allMenuPricing = "";
var allSF = "";

var venueName = "";
var venuePrice = 0;
var tentName = "";
var tentPrice = 0;
var DF = "";
var DFPrice = 0;
var menuName = "";
var menuPrice = 0;
var serviceFee = 0;

var getGuests = null;
var totalField = null;
var venueField = null;
var tentField = null;
var DFField = null;
var menuField = null;

//Get Fields
function getFields()
{
     getGuests = document.getElementById('Guests');
     totalField = document.getElementById('TotalField');
     depositField = document.getElementById('DepositField');
     venueField = document.getElementById('getValue');
     tentField = document.getElementById('getTent');
     DFField = document.getElementById('getDF');
     menuField = document.getElementById('getMenu');
     serviceField = document.getElementById('getServiceCharge');
}

function convertAllArrays()
{
    <?php
    $allVenues=getVenues(); 
    $allVenuePricing=getVenuePricing();
    $allTents=getTents(); 
    $allTentPricing=getTentPricing();
    $allDFPricing=getDFPricing();
    $allMenus=getMenus(); 
    $allMenuPricing=getMenuPricing();
    $allSF=getServiceFee(); 

    //##################Declaring All Arrays###########################\\
        echo "allVenues = ". json_encode($allVenues) . ";\n"; //All the Venue Names
        echo "allVenuePricing = ". json_encode($allVenuePricing) . ";\n"; //All the Venue Pricing
        echo "allTents = ". json_encode($allTents) . ";\n"; //All the Tent Names
        echo "allTentPricing = ". json_encode($allTentPricing) . ";\n"; //All the Tent Pricing 
        echo "allDFPricing = ". json_encode($allDFPricing) . ";\n"; //All the Dance Floors
        echo "allMenus = ". json_encode($allMenus) . ";\n"; //All the Menu Names
        echo "allMenuPricing = ". json_encode($allMenuPricing) . ";\n"; //All the Menu Pricing
        echo "allSF = ". json_encode($allSF) . ";\n"; //All the Service Fees
    ?>
}

function activeControl()
{

    //Check Venue Field
    if(getGuests.value > 0)
    {
        venueField.disabled = false;
    }else{
        venueField.options[0].selected = true;
        venuePrice = 0;
        venueName = "";
        venueField.disabled = true; 
    }

    //Check Tent Field
    if(venueField.selectedIndex == 1)
    {
        tentField.disabled = false;
    }else{  
        tentPrice = 0;
        tentName = "";
        tentField.options[1].selected = true;
        tentField.disabled = true;
    }

    //Check Menu Field
    if(venueField.selectedIndex > 0)
    {
        menuField.disabled = false;
    }else{
        menuPrice = 0;
        menuName = "";
        menuField.options[0].selected = true;
        menuField.disabled = true;  
    }

    //Check Dance Floor Field
    if(venueField.selectedIndex == 1)
    {
        DFField.disabled = false;
    }else{
        DFField.checked = false;
        DF = "No";
        DFPrice = 0;
        DFField.disabled = true;    

    }

    updateTotal();
}

function updateTotal()
{   

    //Get Venue Details 
    var getSelectedVenue = venueField.selectedIndex;
    if(getSelectedVenue > 0)
    {
        venueName = allVenues[getSelectedVenue];
        venuePrice = allVenuePricing[getSelectedVenue]
    }

    //Get Tent Details  
    var getSelectedTent = tentField.selectedIndex;
    if(getSelectedTent > 1)
    {
        tentName = allTents[getSelectedTent-1];
        tentPrice = allTentPricing[getSelectedTent-1]
    }else if(getSelectedTent == 1)
    {
        tentName = "";
        tentPrice = 0;
    }

    //Get DF Details    
    if(DFField.checked)
    {
        DF = "Yes";
        DFPrice = allDFPricing[1];
    }else
    {
        DF = "No";
        DFPrice = 0;
    }

    //Get Menu Details  
    var getSelectedMenu = menuField.selectedIndex;
    if(getSelectedMenu > 0)
    {
        menuName = allMenus[getSelectedMenu];
        menuPrice = allMenuPricing[getSelectedMenu]
    }

    //Get Service Fee Details   
    var getSelectedSF =serviceField.selectedIndex;
    if(getSelectedSF > 0)
    {
        serviceFee = allSF[getSelectedSF];
    }

    venuePrice = parseFloat(venuePrice,10);
    tentPrice = parseFloat(tentPrice,10);
    DFPrice = parseFloat(DFPrice,10);
    menuPrice = parseFloat(menuPrice,10);
    serviceFee = parseFloat(serviceFee,10);


    //Update Total Field
    total = venuePrice + tentPrice +DFPrice + (menuPrice*getGuests.value);
    total = total + (total*serviceFee);
    totalField.value = "R"+total;

    //Update Deposit Fee
    depositField.value = "R"+(total*0.3);
}



</script>
<!--Global Elements-->
```

That is the first 196 lines of the site. Offline it loads, but when uploaded to the webserver, it only uploads up to:

```
function convertAllArrays()
{
```

PS: I know that calling php variables in javascript is not ideal, but it should suffice for my purpose.

!!EDIT!! 
Website Link: http://bloemendal.co.za/Easy-Quote/

!!EDIT!! 
The first few line of code in the function12.inc include. the getVenues() etc functions are declared in this include:

```
<?php
//############################Venues###############################\\
function getVenues()
{
    include("../Includes/db_bloem_01_logon.inc");             
                $cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$passwd,$dbname);
                $query = "SELECT VenueName FROM venues WHERE ID < 5";
                $results = mysqli_query($cxn, $query) or die ("Could't execute query");

      $allVenues= array();

        $counter = 1;
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results))
        {
              extract ($row);
              $allVenues[$counter] = "$VenueName";
              $counter++;
        }     
    return $allVenues;
}

function getVenuePricing()
{
    include("../Includes/db_bloem_01_logon.inc");             
                $cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$passwd,$dbname);
                $query = "SELECT Price FROM venues WHERE ID < 5";
                $results = mysqli_query($cxn, $query) or die ("Could't execute query");

      $allVenuePricing= array();

        $counter = 1;
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results))
        {
              extract ($row);
              $allVenuePricing[$counter] = "$Price";
              $counter++;
        }     
    return $allVenuePricing;
}
```

Comment: Did you check apache logs?

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: Are you getting errors? My guess is that one of your function calls there is throwing a fatal error/exception.

Comment: Just a guess, but it seems that the includes are not available on your webserver or the updated ones are not...

Comment: @viakondratiuk, Thanks, had a quick look, I can only see the general log and nothing out of the ordinary there. The site is hosted by Hetzner, which uses their own, weired, hosting software.

Comment: No, not getting any error, just a blank white screen. And I check the file name for case sensitivity, 100% match, and like I said, offline on my local apache server, everything works, the form even outputs the correct data.

Comment: Try commenting out each PHP function call, one by one, to see if it passes. If one of them is erroring out, you should be able to find which one it is.

Comment: The problem is the convertAllArrays() Function, If I remove that, it loads, so the problem lies somewhere at <?php $allVenues=getVenues();... But I don't know where or why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have php in a script and the php throws an error the error prints in the script tag, so it's not going to show up on your browser. Chances are there's a problem with the php inside your javascript. Move the php outside the script tag to make sure that it runs without error.

Comment: Thanks, did that and I noticed that the problem occurs upon calling getVenues(), the code doesn't load past it, but still no physical error reporting. PS, I commented out the <?php error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); ?>

Comment: hmm it's definately stopping as soon as you start actually doing php, in-fact it's erroring on the getVenues() call. Are you sure error reporting is enabled? php will fail exactly like this if errors are suppressed. Maybe try var_dumping each variable immediately after assigning it.

Comment: Thanks, you got me thinking. I swapped around some include to change to order thing get declared, and vola, now working. Turned out to be my function12.inc causing trouble.

Comment: sounds like you have a dependency on global variables, re-factor to stop using globals, there is a better way, though it may be more complicated you will run into fewer problems like that.

Answer (score 0):

your code

```
$allVenues=getVenues();
```

you can't assing a value to a php variable as a return of a JavaScript function

When the PHP interpreter read your code and build up the web page to be served take the value of **$allVenues** and put it into the page. Let say that variable is **null**: your line of code, served to the browser will be

```
null=getVenues();
```

Comment: Ok, but getVenues() is a php function, declared in the include: function12.inc. I will include that in code now.

Comment: Oh.. I didn't get that. I didn't see the function in the php code and thought it was JS. I think invertedSpear is pointing you in the right direction: see what error PHP is throwing out...

Answer (score 0):

the function

```
mysqli_fetch_assoc
```

doesn't exists (as far as I know)

there is a

```
mysql_fetch_assoc
```

no my-sql-improved

(but is deprecated)